# .flaskenv or .env file not being read

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that uses some enviroment variables, I don't now what has changed but now it doesn't read the variables in the **.flaskenv** file, already tried changing its name to **.env**, still not working.

This is the **.flaskenv** file:

```
    FLASK_APP=app
    FLASK_ENV=development
    CONSUMER_KEY=
    CONSUMER_SECRET=
    ACCESS_KEY=
    ACCESS_SECRET=
    SEC_USERNAME=
    SEC_PASSWORD=
```

In the **app.py** file:

```py
    from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, session, g
    import os

    s_user = os.environ.get('SEC_USERNAME')
    s_pass = os.environ.get('SEC_PASSWORD')

    print(s_user)
    print(s_pass)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

It prints "none".

If i do **flask run** :

```
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate Flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_APP environment variable.

For more information see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/
```

**pip list:**

```
(venv) λ pip list
Package           Version
----------------- ----------
certifi           2020.4.5.2
chardet           3.0.4
click             6.7
Flask             0.12.2
idna              2.9
itsdangerous      0.24
Jinja2            2.10
MarkupSafe        1.0
oauthlib          3.1.0
pip               19.2.3
PySocks           1.7.1
python-dotenv     0.13.0
requests          2.23.0
requests-oauthlib 1.3.0
setuptools        41.2.0
six               1.15.0
tweepy            3.8.0
urllib3           1.25.9
Werkzeug          0.13
```

Comment: Can you provide the line you are running in the command line?

Comment: I'm doing **(venv) λ flask run** and the output is that there is no "FLASK_APP"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As written in the flask docs:

> If python-dotenv is installed, running the flask command will set environment variables defined in the files .env and .flaskenv. This can be used to avoid having to set FLASK_APP manually every time you open a new terminal, and to set configuration using environment variables similar to how some deployment services work.

make sure to run `pip install python-dotenv`

## Edit

This flask seems to be very old, try updating it with

`pip install -U Flask`

Comment: It's installed, I've edited the question with the 'pip list' too